# Wifi not working properly with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on a Intel AC-7260

Tags: networking, drivers, intel, iwlwifi

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on a Thinkpad T540P with a Intel Dual-Band Wireless AC-7260 and the wifi keeps dropping and sometimes it wont allow me to turn it on. What can I do to fix this problem? On Windows I just reverted to an old driver but not sure how I can do that here

ran lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2 command from terminal

```
zahid@zahid-ThinkPad-T540p:/$ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 [8086:08b2] (rev 83)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260 [8086:c270]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

I think it runs fine on 2.4Ghz networks but as soon as I switch to 5Ghz it starts dropping and basically crashes

Edit: More info

```
zahid@zahid-ThinkPad-T540p:~$ dmesg | grep iwl
[    7.605983] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: loaded firmware version 17.948900127.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    7.643324] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7260, REV=0x144
[    7.661871] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: base HW address: 10:4a:7d:0a:60:1d
[    7.864248] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[    8.041793] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0 wlp4s0: renamed from wlan0
```

Edit 21-May-2020

The current state of my WiFi is that it works on both bands longer than it did atleast however the issue is that last night while I was asleep the wifi stopped working yet again during a big upload. Also while I can connect to both of my networks ap just fine if I try connecting to my phones hotspot it doesnt work. VPN does not work as well. Right now I am booted to 4.15 kernel and the it still connects fine to my router but doesnt connect to my hotspot.

Edit2: I should mention that the wifi worked the whole day I was working on my laptop. Only when I went to sleep it stopped working in the middle of the night. That day itself I fixed the wifi or so I thought. I am not even sure what ended up fixing it because last thing I did was add some lines to config file

Comment: [Somewhat related](https://forums.intel.com/s/question/0D50P0000490WDuSAM/dual-band-wireless-7260-ac-wifi-problems-in-windows-10?language=en_US) post here as well. Refer to [akv's answer](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=178577) as it may help you.

Comment: How can I downgrade my kernel? Could you link me a guide? I am definitely sure I have dual band ac-7260 intel

Comment: You can [downgrade your kernel](https://www.maketecheasier.com/downgrade-kernel-linux/) - you should be [running 5.4](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2020/02/ubuntu-20-04-kernel-5-4-lts)

Comment: The problem right now is since I last updated the thread this is the situation which I will point out in the post itself. Check the edit

Comment: If needed I can post logs if that helps

Comment: Booting into an older kernel hasn't helped me